# Mantaflow - slow drip

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I am trying to create an ice melting animation, so need to have my object slowly drip instead of all fluid moving at once. How do I achieve this effect, I have watched plenty of tutorials and have experimented but can only think of one option -

To create a small inflow object and scale it up as it flows to increase the flow.
Is there a simpler solution?

Thanks I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: What is the melting object (what shape)?

Comment: @vklidu it's a cube

Comment: Cube just hanging in the air with water dropping from a corner or cube is getting smaller by melting ? ....do you have some reference of desired result? The whole situation matters becausee visually it can be represented by other ways than fluid sim.

Answer (score 2):

Does it has to be fluid sim?
For dropping water from object like icicles ... probably could be enough two meta balls.

[image]

One main Mball inside the tip and second as drop with just animated Z loc and scale.

[image]

- Animate one cycle and under *NLA Editor* extend dropping by increasing *Repeat* value in range of your animation.
- To make Mballs more seamless you can create whole icicle from meatballs.
- If you would need more frequent dripping you can use particle system rendered Object > MBalls

[image]

Comment: I'm not too sure how to do that. Do I select the verticies on the bottom of the shape or add a new shape?

Comment: Answer extended ... anyway I did answer simple because you didnt provide enough details, so I expected I will delete it ... even now when you specified that object is a Cube it can melts in many visual forms ... so please reference, reference, reference :) Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will remember that for next time

Comment: If you found solution would be great to share. You can do an Answer of your question. This site is knowledge base so probably others can found it useful. And I'm interested too.